# Validation Error is not showing when i am updating data using put in Rest api?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

validation error is not showing.
This is my update function.

```
public function index_put($id)
{
    try
    {
        $input = $this->put();
        if($input)
        {
            $this->form_validation_update();
            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                $this->error_msg();
            }
            else
            {
                if($this->db->update('admins', array('id'=>$id))){
                    $this->update_msg();
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("The Data Already Register or The Data is Empty");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
       $error = array($e->getmessage());
       $errormsg = json_encode($error);
       echo $errormsg;
    }

}
```

and now this is my validation query function:

```
public function form_validation_update()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('fname','First Name','trim|required|max_length[128]|xss_clean|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lname','Last Name','trim|required|max_length[128]|xss_clean|alpha');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|xss_clean|max_length[128]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username','User Name','trim|required|max_length[128]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone_no','Phone Number','required|min_length[6]|xss_clean|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('role_id','Role','trim|required|numeric');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address_line_1','Address','required|xss_clean');
}
```

and now this is error message showing function for update query.

```
public function error_msg()
{
        $error = $this->form_validation->error_array();
        $errormsg = array(
                        'code' => 6, 
                        'msg' => 'Details provided are not valid. Please enter valid details.', 
                        'data'=> array('validation_errors' => $error)
                    );
        echo(json_encode($errormsg));
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($error);
        die();
}
```

and this output is

```
{"code":6,"msg":"Details provided are not valid. Please enter valid details.","data":{"validation_errors":[]}}
```

update function is called but not giving data of form validation.
and i also what validation for unique check email is already register or not but not in that id when data is updating

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And Last I Tried This And It's Working Perfectly

```
if ($this->CI->input->method() !== 'post' && empty($this->validation_data))
    {
        return $this;
    }
```

To,

```
if ($this->CI->input->method() !== 'post' && $this->CI->input->method() !== 'put' && empty($this->validation_data))
    {
        return $this;
    }
```

In Form Validation Library File Because I request Through put and i have to assign put in the method

Answer (score 1):

By default form validation library uses $_POST to validate input data.
To validate Put request data, you manually need to pass put data to the library before running validation.

```
$this->form_validation->set_data($input);
```